# C++ string parsing: how to detect the end of a message?

Tags: c++, string, serial-port, communication, string-parsing

On an embedded system, I would like to parse data that arrives via serial interface (RS232). The data arrives one line at a time (lines are separated with `\r` characters and by some time) from a proprietary source. See example data below.

What I would like to do is to parse whole *messages* (that consist of multiple lines). How could I do that? As I can *hook* on every received char (they are received via ISR), I think I could write the received data to a `std::stringstream` and parse it after a complete message was received. But how can one detect the end of such a message?

Example data:

```
...
X20\r
R46 P20 A231 \r
R45 P20 A287 \r
R44 P20 A347 \r
X21\r
R46 P21 A284 \r
R45 P21 A341 \r
R44 P21 A436 \r
X22\r
R46 P22 A319 \r
R45 P22 A386 \r
R44 P22 A455 \r
...
```

where

```
X22\r
R46 P22 A319 \r
R45 P22 A386 \r
R44 P22 A455 \r
```

is an example for *one message*. I care for

e.g. X = `22`, R46 = `319`, R45 = `386`, R44 = `455`

How can I discriminate the messages in an elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what kind of limitations you have due to it being an embedded system and what guarantees you have on the received data (which seem to lack a terminating symbol for a message) there's probably better solutions but my two suggestions would be:

1/ If the format is guaranteed to be as uniform as it looks in your example you can just store everything in a buffer and wait until a set number of characters have been read and then parse.

2/ Read one character at a time, storing them in a buffer. When you read a 'X' (which seems to be the character signalling the beginning of a new message) just parse the buffer, empty it, store the 'X' and then keep going.

Comment: 1: The data is not guaranteed to be perfectly uniform (`R46 P22 A5 \r` vs. `R46 P22 A5432 \r`), but I will give it a try.    2: Waiting for the next `X` wastes some time (there is a delay between every two lines of data) and is therefore not ideal.

Comment: @plats1 Are you saying that a complete message could have any line count?

Comment: @wonkorealtime A message can consist of exactly one `X...` line and one to four `R...` lines (the messages in my example having three `R...` lines).

Comment: @plats1 If the data is not guaranteed to be uniform, has no predictable length and no terminating character I, personally, can't really see any other way than going with something similar to option number 2 I suggested above. Maybe someone smarter can though =)

Comment: @Pzc You are probably right. The actual system has different states which decide over the number of lines. It is therefore very likely for two consecutive messages to be of the same size. That fact distracted me from accepting answer 2. But I think you are right. I will give it a try and will see how big the impact of those extra delays will be. Thank you.